# Why can't the value of ViewBag be cleared after PostBack?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

My controller name is *"demo"*. I write 2 actions with the same name *"Index"*. The first uses **[HttpGet]** and the seconds is **[HttpPost]**.

But, when I require a PostBack from View, the value of *ViewBag.Name* in the action `[HttpGet] public ActionResult Index() {}` can't be cleared.

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Name = "HttpGet";
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
        {
            ViewBag.Name = "HttpPost";
            return View();
        }
```

In RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "newroute",
                url: "demo/index/{type}",
                defaults: new { controller = "demo", action = "Index", type = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

and the View:

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Index", "demo", new { type = @ViewBag.Name })">
    <input type="submit" value="Click me" />
</form>

@ViewBag.Name
```

Here is my problem: When I click the button, the value of `@ViewBag.Name` in the page is **"HttpPost"**. But, in URL, it's `/demo/index/HttpGet`

Why?

Comment: Probably better title should say something like "how to create url to POST action using Url.Action"... (or maybe not... I guess I'm not sure what exactly your are looking for).

Comment: Why are you including `HttpGet` as part of the route URL? That seems like an odd thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you navigate to this page with a GET request, you're executing method `Index()`, and as the page is rendered the `Name` is `HttpGet`, so it will create the URL for the form action as /demo/index/HttpGet.

Later, once you press the button, you're posting to that very URL created in the previous step, but since the form is POSTing you're executing `Index(FormCollection form)`, and that sets `Name` to `HttpPost`. The URL remains what it was generated at the previous step.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Name = "HttpGet";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
    {
        ViewBag.Name = "HttpPost";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```